# Switch a4j (richfaces) tabPanel programmatically with Javascript

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tabpanel, ajax4jsf

When I click a commandButton, I would like to execute some js to switch the current tab panel to another tab panel.  My tabPanel is switchType="client".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
RichFaces.switchTab('tabPanelId','tabLabel','tabId') method to change tabs.
```

Detailed information can be found [here](http://community.jboss.org/thread/147167?tstart=-1)